# Entity Framework Core - Get multiple rows from one table as one DTO with multiple properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to select two rows into one anonymous object DTO with two properties?
With a model like:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

I am writing a method that finds the difference between two versions of a document:

```
public Task<string> CompareVersions(int initialId, int finalId)
```

So I need to retrieve the text of exactly two `Documents` by Id, and I need know which was which.

Currently I am constructing a `Dictionary<int, string>` by doing:

```
var dto = await _context.Documents
    .Where(doc => doc.Id == initialId
               || doc.Id == finalId)
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Id, x => x.Text);
```

and then calling `dto[initialId]` to get the text. However, this feels very cumbersome. Is there any way to take the two Ids and select them into one DTO in the form

```
{
    InitialText,
    FinalText
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `SelectMany`

```cs
var query = 
   from initial in _context.Documents
   where initial.Id = initialId
   from final in _context.Documents
   where final.Id = finalId
   select new 
   {
      InitialText = initial.Text,
      FinalText = final.Text
   };

var result = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: While I prefer lambda style over query style, this version is so much more elegant I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate can do it too

```
var dto = (await _context.Documents
.Where(doc => doc.Id == initialId || doc.Id == finalId).ToListAsync())
.Aggregate(
  new { InitialText = "", FinalText = "" }, 
  (seed, doc) => { 
    if(doc.Id == initialId) 
      seed.InitialText = doc.Text; 
    else
      seed.FinalText = doc.Text;
  }
);
```

I'm not sure I like it any more than I do your dictionary approach, but with an actual dto at the end rather than the dictionary:

```
var d = await _context.Documents
.Where(doc => doc.Id == initialId || doc.Id == finalId)
.ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Id, x => x.Text);
var dto = new { InitialText = d[initialId], FinalText = d[finalId] };
```

You could also perhaps just:

```
var dto = new { 
  InitialText = await context.Documents
.FindAsync(initialId),
  FinalText = await context.Documents
.FindAsync(finalId)
};
```